# Removed Core Location from application but still being asked for users location

Tags: ios, core-location

I removed the Core Location framework from an existing iOS application. I removed all relevant code which requires Core Location.

Even after deleting the build from the device and deploying a new build, I am still receiving a prompt asking for my location.

I had a similar problem before and had to format the device. Problem is, this is version 2 of an application which is already released. I do not want users prompted for Core Location if I am not going to use it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you accessing the Photo Library?

Comment: @PaulCezanne No I am not. I even disabled everything to do with MapKit! This is crazy.

Comment: Wild..., I know Photo Library pictures can have location info. Try this. Reset the simulator, run your app, see if it still needs it.

Comment: @PaulCezanne This only happens on devices. Simulator is fine. I completely uninstall the app and re-install. I've cleaned, deleted derived data, used iPhone explorer to see if any files were left behind on the device, but nothing fixes the issue.

Comment: mmmm, restore the phone to factory, install your app, see if it still does it?

Comment: Do you have any analytics or ad network libraries installed in your app?

Comment: @PaulCezanne Formatting the device works, but this is a 2.0 release and I do not want to tell users they have to uninstall.

Comment: @ScottBossak I have Google Analytics, but I cannot find anywhere it is using Core Location. I also have AdMob and cannot find anywhere it is using Core Location.

Comment: formatting was just to prove that it WASN'T in your app. I had kind of hoped it wouldn't work, so that fixing your app would fix the problem. Now we know it ISN'T in your app, so, yikes!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your Info.plist file?  You might have "App registers for location updates" in your "Required background modes" section.

Comment: This does not appear in my plist.

Answer (score 0):

Did your app `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` or did you use `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:`? If you did, the os might still have your app registered for these. Then you would just have to stop these and it should work.